# dynamically change onclick and ontouchstart with the href for colorbox modal

Tags: jquery, mobile, onclick, colorbox, touch-event

Im trying to get colorbox working inside my mobile app. Because of some touch events I have to use the `ontouchstart` and `onclick` event to fire my colorbox modal.

I've specified my colorbox settings within the document ready. Here I create an ajax colorbox for all the `class="ajax"`. I do not want to create a new function for every link I add. So I still want to use the `href="ajax.html`"

How can I dynamically populate the `onclick` and `ontouchstart` so they follow the `href` of that link? Also, they should be able to open this in the same ajax colorbox settings.

This is what i have now which, of course, doesn't work.

```
<head>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".ajax").colorbox({
            transition: 'fade',
            speed:200,
            initialWidth: '0',
            initialHeight: '0',
            width: '800px',
            maxWidth:'95%',
             maxHeight:'95%',
            opacity: .6
            });

    });

    function modalAjax(){  
  $.colorbox({href: });

}

</script>

</head>

<a href="ajax.html" ontouchstart="modalAjax()" onclick="modalAjax()" class="ajax"> Link works on mobile and desktop </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the modalAjax function to something like the following in your script tag:

```
<script> 
    function modalAjax( extraOptions ){ 

        var _defaultSettings = {
                transition: 'fade',
                speed:200,
                initialWidth: '0',
                initialHeight: '0',
                width: '800px',
                maxWidth:'95%',
                maxHeight:'95%',
                opacity: .6
            }
            ,settings = _defaultSettings;

        $.extend(settings, extraOptions);
        $.colorbox(settings);
    }   
</script>
```

Then, you can perform your event bindings in your html markup like this:

```
<a href="ajax.html" ontouchstart="modalAjax({href: $(this).attr('href')})" onclick="modalAjax({href: $(this).attr('href')})" class="ajax"> Link works on mobile and desktop </a>
```

or in javascript as well if you want the behavior applied to all your DOM elements with class "ajax":

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ajax").bind('touchstart click', function() { 
        modalAjax( { href: $(this).attr('href') } );
    });
});
```

Remember to remove the inline HTML bindings if you choose to do the latter.